# How can I find the root cause for bazel error Worker process did not return a WorkResponse?

Tags: java, bazel

My bazel v4.0.0. build just shows me this unclear `Worker process did not return a WorkResponse` error message which seems to hide the root cause of the problem. It happens when I include a processor in the `java_library` target.

This is a reduced version of my bazel BUILD file:

```
java_library(
    name="java",
    srcs=glob(["**/*.java"]),
    plugins = [
        ":my_processor",
    ],
)

java_plugin(
    name = "my_processor",
    processor_class = "mypackage.MyProcessor",
)
```

How to find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there's more scenarios that could cause this error, my what worked for me as a is to specify `--noexperimental_worker_multiplex`.

The command `bazel build //myproject/src/main/java --noexperimental_worker_multiplex` changed the error message but most importantly it revealed: Did you try to print something to stdout?

And indeed the processor appeared to contain a `System.out.println`. Removing it resolved this build error.

B.t.w. I did remove the `--noexperimental_worker_multiplex` after the problem was solved, because I think the experimental_worker_multiplex is a good thing.